# Google DataStudio (LookerStudio?) Can't connect to RDS MySQL using SSL?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds

I am attempting to connect to an RDS MySQL instance from Google DataStudio (LookerStudio?). The RDS instance accessible via public internet. I'm able to connect to it successfully using non-ssl connection.

Attempting to connect to it via ssl fails i get

```
Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.

Error ID: f8e60d8e
and no additional details.
```

[image: screenshot]

I can verify the ssl connection works because I create a connection using the same details and pem file in a separate client and it works without issue.

the server certificate is in pem format. it comes directly from aws.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.RegionCertificates

why do i get this error and how do i resolve it?